# Difference between the following two method calls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(customFoo:) withObject:obj waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and

```
[self customFoo:obj];
```

As I know, if second one is invoked on the main thread, there isn't any difference between two of them... is it right?

What are the basic differences between two of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run-time behaviours are the same. But when compiling the code there is a difference: The second will only compile if the method `customFoo:` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

**performSelector:** Sends a specified message to the receiver and returns the result of the message.

PerformSelector is used to call method as you want perform that means that you have option to select different option for performing particular task(Method) Example...

```
– performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: // will execute method after specific delay.. 
– performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes: 
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: 
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: 
– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
```

`– performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` // Perform task in background. So, Your ManinThread(Application) will not stop responding..like multithreading..

Where direct method (`[self customFoo:obj];`) will not provide selection for performing task..

[For more and detailed explanation visit this reference..](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope,this will help you...